# Accessing Environment Variables in applicationhost.config

Tags: environment-variables, iis-express

I have an environment variable `MyLocation`
When I set the virtual directory physical path to this environment variable in applicationhost.config. We get 404 everywhere, meaning the variable was not set correctly.

```
 <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%MyLocation%" />
```

I verified that the variable exists. Tried it under machine and user.

Our applicationhost.config is included in TFS, this is why we want to set the location as an environment variable. Anyone tried this? and had any luck with it?

Answer (score -1):

It works for me with IIS Express 10.0.18362.1